# JSON problem? MMA10, Windows 7 or Linux Mint

Tags: json-format

I want to test Mathematica 10 to import various data format. In this case, I have a JSON file with the following data and structure:

```
{ "_id" : "ac3", "name" : "AC3 Phone", "brand" : "ACME", "type" : "phone", "price" : 200, "warranty_years" : 1, "available" : true }
{ "_id" : "ac7", "name" : "AC7 Phone", "brand" : "ACME", "type" : "phone", "price" : 320, "warranty_years" : 1, "available" : false }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bf9" }, "name" : "AC3 Series Charger", "type" : [ "accessory", "charger" ], "price" : 19, "warranty_years" : 0.25, "for" : [ "ac3", "ac7", "ac9" ] }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfa" }, "name" : "AC3 Case Green", "type" : [ "accessory", "case" ], "color" : "green", "price" : 12, "warranty_years" : 0 }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfb" }, "name" : "Phone Extended Warranty", "type" : "warranty", "price" : 38, "warranty_years" : 2, "for" : [ "ac3", "ac7", "ac9", "qp7", "qp8", "qp9" ] }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfc" }, "name" : "AC3 Case Black", "type" : [ "accessory", "case" ], "color" : "black", "price" : 12.5, "warranty_years" : 0.25, "available" : false, "for" : "ac3" }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfd" }, "name" : "AC3 Case Red", "type" : [ "accessory", "case" ], "color" : "red", "price" : 12, "warranty_years" : 0.25, "available" : true, "for" : "ac3" }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfe" }, "name" : "Phone Service Basic Plan", "type" : "service", "monthly_price" : 40, "limits" : { "voice" : { "units" : "minutes", "n" : 400, "over_rate" : 0.05 }, "data" : { "units" : "gigabytes", "n" : 20, "over_rate" : 1 }, "sms" : { "units" : "texts sent", "n" : 100, "over_rate" : 0.001 } }, "term_years" : 2 }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bff" }, "name" : "Phone Service Core Plan", "type" : "service", "monthly_price" : 60, "limits" : { "voice" : { "units" : "minutes", "n" : 1000, "over_rate" : 0.05 }, "data" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 }, "sms" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 } }, "term_years" : 1 }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15c00" }, "name" : "Phone Service Family Plan", "type" : "service", "monthly_price" : 90, "limits" : { "voice" : { "units" : "minutes", "n" : 1200, "over_rate" : 0.05 }, "data" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 }, "sms" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 } }, "sales_tax" : true, "term_years" : 2 }
    { "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15c01" }, "name" : "Cable TV Basic Service Package", "type" : "tv", "monthly_price" : 50, "term_years" : 2, "cancel_penalty" : 25, "sales_tax" : true, "additional_tarriffs" : [ { "kind" : "federal tarriff", "amount" : { "percent_of_service" : 0.06 } }, { "kind" : "misc tarriff", "amount" : 2.25 } ] }
```

When I try to import this file in Mathematica, it's an error:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\Steeve Brechmann\\Desktop\\products.json", "JSON"]
Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as JSON format. >>
```

I've imported successfully this file in a MongoDB database so I guess the file is ok. Any ideas?

Steeve

Comment: It's the same in v9. Besides, if you paste it into http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and click "viewer" to try to display the data it says that the JSON is invalid.